# Providing a label name in plotly express

Tags: python, plotly-express

Hi I am wondering how to give a label name when using plotly express where the data is not in the form of a `DataFrame`.
Its not possible to use the keyword argument `name` when using `px.line`. However it is a possible when using `px.scatter` function.

As a result in the example below I end up with a legend name only for the second trace.

I am aware this can be easily done using `plotly.graph_objs` but wondering how to do in `plotly.express`

```
import plotly.express as px 
history_dict = history.history

p1 = px.line(
    x = np.arange(0,20),
    y = history_dict["loss"],
    # error if name keyword argument used here.
    title = "Training and Validation Loss",   
)

p1.add_scatter(
    x = np.arange(0,20),
    y = history_dict["val_loss"],
    mode = "lines",
    name = "val loss"
)

p1.update_layout(xaxis_title = "epochs", yaxis_title = "loss")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have drawn the first line plot, you need to specify that you would like to display the legend and the name you want to provide. Add these lines between `px.line()` and `p1.add_scatter()`

```
p1['data'][0]['showlegend']=True
p1['data'][0]['name']='Loss'
```

**Plot**

[image]

Comment: [You can also have the legend entries each show near the end (or beginning) of their line trace](https://plotly.com/python/line-charts/#label-lines-with-annotations) but that takes a lot of extra work.